# Mock object for a method without dependency injection

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to test a method of a class that instantiates another object
and calls a method of this object.

How can I mock this object and its method `Foo2` and `run()`  without dependency injection?

Is this possible or do I need to modify the code for Foo class to inject the object?

```
class Foo {

    public function bar()
    {
        $foo2 = new Foo2();
        $data = $foo2->run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently find a nice features in [Mockery](https://packagist.org/packages/mockery/mockery) (a mock object framework for PHP) [called Mocking Hard Dependencies (new Keyword)](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mocking_hard_dependencies.html#mocking-hard-dependencies-new-keyword) that permit you to overload/mock class instantiated in a method. As Example:

```
use Mockery as m;
class BarTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testBar()
    {
        $param = 'Testing';

        $externalMock = m::mock('overload:Foo\Bar2');
        $externalMock->shouldReceive('run')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn('Tested!');

        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->bar();
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: What is Bar2 in m::mock('overload:Foo\Bar2'); ??

Answer (score 0):

use the mock-facilities of phpunit:

However, you should consider to split your bar() methods logic into two separate methods to split the instantiation and the execution, e.g.:

```
bar() {
    $foo2 = $this->getFooImplementation();
    $data = $foo2->run();    
}
```

you're then able to mock the call of getFooImplementation():

```
$fooInstance = $this->getMockBuilder('Foo')->setMethods(array('getFooImplementation'))->getMock();
$fooInstance->expects($this->at(0))->method('getFooImplementation')->willReturn(new Foo3());
```